# How to install 2 instances of Kerbal Space Program from Steam, on one computer?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

KSP loads slowly. Sometimes very slowly. More parts and addons, slower loading. So I want to have a second instance, with no mods and only some of the stock parts, to quickly test things.

I bought my copy on Steam, so I don't have any kind of installation media. How can I install second instance on the same computer, from the same steam account? I don't want to lost my current instance as I have nice career going on (with a lot of mods).

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I've never transferred my purchase to Steam.

Comment: @MBraedley I never transferred it. I got it, Steam gift code. And at the time it was simply the cheapset option, too.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but: Have you updated to the latest KSP?  The last patch optimized the load times, and it now loads in about 1/10 the time on my PC.  I believe its version 0.23 that has all the optimizations.

Comment: @Mołot not saying you ever had the option to transfer, just saying I haven't exercised my option.  It is a bit unfortunate that there isn't a great way to have modded and unmodded installs with Steam.

Comment: Seems like what you actually need is a mod organizer with profiles.

Comment: @Arian if it exists, and works pre-launch, not in-game, then probably yes.

Answer (score 7):

I've done this myself. When I was wanting to play with FAR, but have a save without it, I just copied the Kerbal Space Program directory from the SteamApps folder to another location on my hard drive, and it runs just fine.

I will also note that this was done with .23, so I can't imagine why it wouldn't work currently.

Answer (score 6):

You can create another version but it won't be linked to Steam. Go to your steamapps folder, common, Kerbal Space Program.

Copy it and keep it safe (unless you want to reinstall all of your mods)

Then delete the KSP folder from your steam directory.

Restart steam and try to launch KSP again. It'll start re-downloading all the file necessary since you deleted them(gj).

Now after that's done go back to the steam directory and copy that and keep it somewhere safe. THIS IS YOUR VANILLA STEAM FOLDER.

You can either choose to make the Vanilla KSP the one steam launches. If that's your goal, you're done.

If you want to make the modded KSP your steam launch, simply copy the Vanilla one and keep it somewhere else(don't get it mixed up, label properly). After you've done that, copy the modded one and replace the Vanilla with it.

Voila, c'est bon, oui?

Comment: Also - you can add non-steam shortcuts to steam, so you can still have the steam overlay in either version if you want.